# Printing CGFloat in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get familiar with the Swift and test several things.

Here's a strange thing which I can't understand.

```
var count : NSInteger   = 19
var percent : CGFloat   = 22.01
var random : NSInteger  = NSInteger(percent)

NSLog("%d, %f, %d", count, percent, random);
println("\(count), \(percent), \(random)")
```

It should print 19, 22.01, 22 but the log is...

```
19, 0.000000, 33875549
19, 22.0100002288818, 22
```

What's wrong here? After I removed the type specifier, it works fine with `println` not with `NSLog`.

Any Idea why the log is not correct?

---

**ADDED**

What about println? Using `\()` has no way to print 22.01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you're compiling for 32-bit iOS, where `CGFloat` is a 32-bit `float`.

The closest `float` to 22.01 is exactly 22.0100002288818359375.

The closest 64-bit `double` to 22.01 is exactly 22.010000000000001563194018672220408916473388671875.

It appears that Swift string interpolation converts a `double` to the shortest string that would convert back to exactly the same `double`.  It converts a `float` to a `double` (with the extra bits being zeros), then converts the `double` to a string as if it had been given a `double` in the first place.

The shortest string that converts back to `Double(22.010000000000001563194018672220408916473388671875)` is `22.01`.  But the shortest string that converts back to `Double(22.0100002288818359375)` is `22.0100002288818`.

Answer (score 2):

CGFloats are weird since they can be 32 or 64 bit depending on the system. It seems that NSLog has an issue with them. If you type percent explicitly as a Float or Double it will work correctly. You can also get the native type with cgfloat.native.

```
NSLog("%d, %f, %d", count, percent.native, random);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `%@` for `CGFloat` and it works fine:

```
NSLog("%d, %@, %d", count, percent, random);
```

This works because you can call `.description` on a `CGFloat`.